# How to write data into multiple files in a directory

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been stuck for hours on how to write my crawled data into multiple files. I wrote a code that scraps a website and extracts all the body of each link in the website. An example is crawling news website and you extract all the links and then extracts all the body of each links. I have done that succesffully But now my concern now is that instead of storing them all into a file using this code below

```
def save_data(data):
the_file = open('raw_data.txt', 'w')
for title_text, body_content, url in data:
    the_file.write("%s\n" % [title_text, body_content, url])
```

how do I write the code such that I store each article in a different file. So I would be having something like Article_00, Article_01, Article_01...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the data in multiple files, then you must open multiple files for writing.

Use `enumerate` to get a counter for which data set you're iterating over, so you can use it in the filename like this:

```
def save_data(data):
    for i, (title_text, body_content, url) in enumerate(data):
        file = open('Article_%02d' % (i,), 'w+')
        file.write("%s\n" % [title_text, body_content, url])
        file.close()
```